# I am trying to copy a selection from one worksheet to another using vba and style the new sheet but one set of column values is not copying over

Tags: vba, excel

I can get everything but the original column "U" to copy over (which is a date field). Literally everything else works but this one field, any ideas as to why this one field would not copy over?

Here's what I wrote so far:

```
Sub CopiesandMovesReferralDatafromOLAB()


    Cells.Select

    Range("D:D,C:C,E:E,AM:AM,F:F,R:R,AI:AI,AJ:AJ,U:U").Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("A1").Select 
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("B1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("C1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("D1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("E1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("F1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("G1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("H1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("I1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"
        Range("J1").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "xxx"

        Range("A1:J1").Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With

        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 10053222
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: [Must read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513)

Comment: i get it but this is what i'm working with right now

Comment: Just saying, you'll *want* to fix that to avoid *further* errors down the line, *and* to end up with code that's easier to read, to maintain, and more importantly, to debug. Like what you're trying to do right now.

Comment: i don't know how to use variables and what not (i'm not a programmer) and don't know how to convert what i have to that format

Comment: It copied column U when I tested it.  You have 9 columns selected when you copy and you're placing `xxx` in 10 columns, so maybe is working as expected?  The copied columns appear in the alphabetical order - so column U appears in column F after pasting (6th column being copied).

Comment: yea i messed that up sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why column U wouldn't copy over, but work with objects instead, and supply the destination range to the `Copy` method, so that you don't need two instructions, and you're not pasting on whatever random cell is currently active in that destination worksheet - if that cell is `A1`, then your header row is currently overwriting the first row of data you're pasting over:

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

Dim targetBook As Workbook
Set targetBook = Application.Workbooks.Add

Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
Set targetSheet = targetBook.Worksheets(1)

With sourceSheet.Range("D:D,C:C,E:E,AM:AM,F:F,R:R,AI:AI,AJ:AJ,U:U")
    .Copy targetSheet.Range("A2")
End With
```

As for the rest... use `With` blocks to work *with* a given specific `Range`, instead of successively `.Select`ing each individual cell and working with `ActiveCell` like macro-recorder "code":

```
Dim headings() As Variant
headings = Array("Column1","Column2","Column3", ..., "Column10")

With targetSheet.Range("A1:J1")
    .value = headings
    With .Font
        .Bold = True
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With .Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10053222
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0            
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
```

---

> *I don't know how to use variables and what not (I'm not a programmer)*

You're writing code, you're programming. Not knowing everything is normal, you're here to learn. As long as you're *willing* to learn, nothing will stop you. Declare local variables with `Dim`, assign object references with the `Set` keyword, specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, and you'll do great!

Comment: Sorry - I've been getting frustrated with this. And I realized it was copying over U (I'm an idiot). I'll try this out. Thanks!

Comment: Ok - I tried this and I can get it to create the header row in the format I need. However, I have two questions:


1. I need to put specific header titles that are unique to this report, how do I do that? Within this range `With targetSheet.Range("A1:J1")
    .Value = " "`


2. Doing this did not bring over any data from this range: `With sourceSheet.Range("D:D,C:C,E:E,AM:AM,F:F,B:B,R:R,AI:AI,AJ:AJ,U:U")
    .Copy targetSheet.Range("A2")`
a. I also need the columns to be in the order of the range above

Comment: @K.Rheinheimer I've edited my answer to make it easy to specify distinct headers, see revision.

Comment: Ah that's amazing, thank you. One more thing - the range that I am moving over is out of the order selected in the first With statement, is there a way to maintain that order?

Comment: The behavior should be identical to what it would be if you selected the columns manually holding down Ctrl key and then copying - the order doesn't change, but Excel pastes them one next to the other.

Comment: Currently it's copying them in alphabetical order of the range selection, I.E. columns B, C, D, E, F....etc

Comment: I got it, I googled and found a different macro to add to do the rearranging!